# unty3d rotate player to stand on planet

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I have a player that will "fall" to a planet, a sphere, and stand on it vertically. the planet handles its own gravity where it rotates the player to be upright, but locks the players y axis.

The gravity.js script detects if an object is a player, hit, and executes this on the player, locking rotation of the player:

```
hit.transform.LookAt(/*hit.transform.position + */transform.position);
hit.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3(hit.transform.eulerAngles.x - 90, hit.transform.eulerAngles.y, hit.transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

How to free just the y axis but no more though?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do. But if the gravity.js is attached to the player, you could do the following:

```
hit.transform.LookAt(/*hit.transform.position + */transform.position);
hit.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3(hit.transform.eulerAngles.x - 90, this.transform.eulerAngles.y, hit.transform.eulerAngles.z);
```

The eulerAngles y axis is just set to what it currently is.
I don't know Unitys JavaScript so this is from my C# knowledge. You might have to adapt it. You might want to read this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/wiki/faq :) no offense!

Another way to do what you want to accomplish is to tick the constraint checkboxes on the rigidbody if your player has one:

[image: Unity3D Rigidbody]

Comment: well I don't want to lock the players x and z rotations, but locally lock them accordingly to where the player is on the planet. for instance, if the player is on the bottom of the planet, they need to be upside-down, but not prevent the player from rotating on the LOCAL y axis. that is critical to the game to even work in the first place. lets say the player is on the side of the planet, the player will stand on the planet but the code I gave locks the player from rotating on the local y axis.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think thats the way to go. If you player stands upright on the planet (feed touch ground, head to the clouds, doesn't matter if top or bottom side of planet) the look direction for left and right will always be its local y axis. So why lock anything? Have you tried to search Unity answers/forums/google for  "Planet Walker" or "Spherical Gravity"? I found a lot of usefull stuff.

Comment: searched, but used different keywords. I will try these as they seem far more promising than the ones I used before. thank you! @Wipster